# QSortFilterProxyModel QTableView 5.3 not sorting/updating?

Tags: qt, qtableview, qsortfilterproxymodel

Qt 5.3.0 & 5.3.1 Linux

I've subclassed QSortFilterProxyModel and implemented lessThan().
When someone clicks the tableview header (which Ive 'connect'ed to)
and I call invalidate(), I see it call 'lessThan' but the tableview never
updates.  Can someone tell me what Im missing?  lessThan() is definitely 
sorting things properly as I put some print statements to see what was
happening inside there when it was called.  I've also tried adding
table->repaint() which doesn't do anything.

Here's my code:

```
QTableView *table = m_ui->tableView;
table->resize(930, 200);
table->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
table->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
table->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
table->verticalHeader()->hide();

QStringList header;
header << "ID";
header << "Prefix";
header << "First";
header << "M";
header << "Last";
int cols = header.size();

BookcaseModel *bookcaseModel = new BookcaseModel(this, cols, header);
m_proxy_bookcase = new SortFilterProxyModelBookcase(this);
m_proxy_bookcase->setSourceModel(bookcaseModel);
m_proxy_bookcase->sort(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);
m_proxy_bookcase->setDynamicSortFilter(true);
m_proxy_bookcase->setSortRole(Qt::DisplayRole);

table->setModel(bookcaseModel);
table->setSortingEnabled(true);
table->horizontalHeader()->setSortIndicator(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);
table->horizontalHeader()->setSectionsClickable(true);

connect(table->horizontalHeader(), SIGNAL(sectionClicked(int)),
        this, SLOT(selectedColumnSlot(int)));
```

Then the slot:

```
void selectedColumnSlot(int col) 
{
    m_proxy_bookcase->sort(col, Qt::DescendingOrder);
    m_proxy_bookcase->invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Considering this line:

```
table->setModel(bookcaseModel);
```

It seems your table is showing the underlying model, not the proxy. It should be:

```
table->setModel(m_proxy_bookcase);
```

When you sort a model using a proxy, it doesn't modify the source model; only the proxy knows the order of elements after the call to `sort()`. That's why your view must show the proxy rather than the source model.

And (I might be wrong) I don't think the call to `invalidate()` after `sort()` is useful.